# Compile Warnings Reports in TFS

Tags: tfs, build, warnings, reporting, foundation

I have the following environment:

- We use Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 to daily build our
  system which consists of hundreds of C# projects.
- Our code quality department has identified a set of 194 C# code
  analysis rules that we must keep to a minimum.
- The compilation produces around 80,000 code analysis warnings that
  belong to the 194 code quality rules.
- 10-20 developers update the system and checkin source files every day

I have the following business requirement:

- Report the progress of the code rule warnings on daily basis in the form of charts and tables.

Objective is to monitor and control the amount of code warnings on daily basis.

According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/table-reference-build-project compile errors are saved in a fact table called FactBuildProject

I am not sure about:

**Are all my 80,000 warnings saved in the TFS warehouse database every day?**

Comment: Did you look in the warehouse?

Comment: yes, I only found the CompileWarnings, which seems to be the warning count. I need the warning IDs cause I need to report on specific group of warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the warnings will be saved with the builds.

For XAML Builds the number of compiler warnings used be stored in TFS Warehouse (**BuildProjectView**).

So, you can get the number of warnings from TFS Warehouse **BuildProjectView**.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Cannot find the specific warning messages or IDs from the TFS Warehouse.

Just I mentioned above, the warnings will be saved with the builds. So, we can try checking the build logs with TFS API. Reference this thread : [How to fetch Build Warning from TFS MS Build or TFS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975484/how-to-fetch-build-warning-from-tfs-ms-build-or-tfs-api)

You can get the build list first, then get the logs in a loop.

Comment: I need the 80,000 warning IDs every day, is this possible?

Comment: @Siraf Just I mentioned above, the warnings will be saved with the builds. So, you can try checking the build logs. I cannot find the specific warning messages or IDs from the TFS Warehouse.

Comment: thanks Andy, your information that the warning IDs are not available in the TFS database is valuable to me, cause this was my guess but I needed a proof

Comment: @Siraf Yes, we can try get the warnings from build logs with TFS API, see the updated answer.

Comment: we will get the warnings from the log files that we already export during the build. Thanks for your support